# How to make an element fixed on the viewport?

Tags: google-app-maker

In the demos, there aren't css rules making the elements stay at fixed relative to the viewport. I don't know how this it is being accomplished.

Comment: Maybe `position: fixed` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. However, the demo doesn't use it, I want to understand what is happening. https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/starter-app/

Comment: Also, when I use `position: fixed` and `z-index: some-number` to *fix* a fragment, the the rest of the page becomes un-scrollable. No idea why this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick of 'fixed' elements in App Maker samples/templates is in fixed(css position absolute) layout of the root panel. To achieve this effect you need just to:

1. Create a page and set its layout to fixed
2. Add elements you want to be fixed and set their position with property editor (top, left, etc..)
3. Then you can add nested content/container/wrapper panel with flow (vertical/horizontal) layout type and tell it to fit to content

**Note:** Of course, you can go and set CSS position: fixed !important for your element, but in this case your page will look scrumbled in editor...

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed.